# How do I make a method that creates a new instance of a generic class specified by an abstract class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, constructor, abstract-class

I'm trying to instantiate and register listener classes in a loop, based on a list of event classes.  I'm trying to use a list such as:

```
static final Class[] USER_EVENTS_HANDLED = {
    FirstEvent.class,
    SecondEvent.class
};
```

I have a bunch of listener classes, one for each:

```
FirstEventListener extends MyAbstractListener<T extends MyEvent>
SecondEventListener extends MyAbstractListener<T extends MyEvent>
```

I'm currently manually registering the event class and listener class explicitly:

```
eventManager.registerListener(FirstEvent.class, new FirstEventListener());
eventManager.registerListener(SecondEvent.class, new SecondEventListener());
```

I'm trying to not duplicate the event name twice, for maintainability.  I build the name of the listener class from the event class, but I'm struggling to come up with the right way to create a new instance of the listener using that.  First tried newInstance, but then realized generics had to be treated specially.  I got something like this snippet of code from somewhere:

```
private static class ListenerGenerator<E> {
    E generateListener(Class<E> clazz, Constructor constructor) throws Exception {
        return (E) constructor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

So to make that work, I tried calling "getConstructor", along with some other approaches, but that keeps resulting in a NoSuchMethod error.

What's the simplest approach to accomplish my goal?

NOTE: This is not a duplicate of the question just asking about creating an instance of a generic class in Java.  It's a more specific case requiring a significantly more complex solution.

Comment: The title is a bit convoluted, but I'm not sure if I can edit that, and I think the description of what I'm trying to accomplish in the body text is clear.

Comment: *What's the simplest approach to accomplish my goal?* Duplicate the event name twice. Done.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are stuck, how are you calling `generateListener`?

Comment: @JornVernee I'm calling it with listenerGenerator.generateListener(listenerClass, listenerClass.getConstructor());

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So you don't know how to instantiate that listener class using reflection?

Comment: I do know how to instantiate the listener class using reflection, you asked what was the simplest approach. Reflection is not the simplest approach. Not even close.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand what you're saying, and ultimately might have decided, yeah, even if I scuttle this crap into a separate method/class/etc, it's still something other people need to understand.  But it wasn't what I was trying to do.  I was wanting to avoid the duplication.  I thought that was clear when I wrote "I'm trying to not duplicate the event name twice".  I wouldn't have needed to spend time on StackOverflow trying to ask for help on this otherwise.

Comment: Fine. Include enough code to make this a MCVE and I'll actually write an answer showing you how you can do this with reflection. It will **require** quite a bit of code. And you will have to modify your method(s). Let's start with the most basic part. `E` has no restrictions on it as your generic type. Should it not relate in some way to a `MyAbstractListener`?

Comment: Also, please expand upon *I build the name of the listener class from the event class and instantiate it, but I'm struggling to come up with the right way to create a new instance of the listener using that.* The first part is directly contradicted by the second.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572534/2970947

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, but I'm going to need to take a break from this.  I've been putting in a lot of extra hours, including some time trying to get this working, and possibly wasn't figuring it out because I'm not feeling right.  Sorry I didn't supply enough information to ask my question.  I'll try again when I'm feeling better and have more time.

Comment: I fixed the typing mistake you pointed out by the way (removed "and instantiated it").  Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Get some rest. Ultimately, I think you want a `Class<? super MyAbstractListener<? super MyEvent>> cls` and `cls.getConstructor(new Class[0]).newInstance(new Object[0]);` be sure to expand upon your question though. Also, specify the version of Java you're using. Because `Class.newInstance()` was deprecated in Java 9.